# How can I catch for a connection timeout error in Python's SMTPlib?

Tags: python, error-handling, smtplib

The error being thrown is:

```
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I'm not sure what to except for?

```
    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com')
        smtpObj.starttls()
        smtpObj.login('user','pass')
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        print "Successfully sent email"
    except smtplib.SMTPException('Error: unable to send email"'):
        pass
    except smtplib.socket.error ('Error: could not connect to server'):
        pass
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code that throws the error?

Comment: I updated the question with the code that throws the error.  It throws the error when the smtp server cannot be contacted.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the exception class, not an instance thereof. That is to say, the code should look like

```
try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com')
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.login('user','pass')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
    print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException: # Didn't make an instance.
    pass
except smtplib.socket.error:
    pass
```

The second exception, `smtplib.socket.error`, seems to be the applicable one to catch that error. It is usually accessed directly from the socket module `import socket`, `socket.error`.

Note that I said that was what the code "should" look like, and that's sort of an exaggeration. When using `try`/`except`, you want to include as little code as possible in the `try` block, especially when you are catching fairly general errors like `socket.error`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `socket.error` should work but if you post the code you're using, we can help you better. `smtplib.SMTPConnectError` should also be of interest.

Try something like this:

```
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP("something.com")
except (socket.error, smtplib.SMTPConnectError):
    print >> stderr, "Error connecting"
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) is the base class for [smtplib.SMTPConnectError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html?highlight=sendmail#smtplib.SMTPConnectError), [socket.timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.timeout), [TimeoutError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TimeoutError), etc. Therefore, you should catch `OSError` if you want to handle them all:

```
try:
    ...
except OSError:
    ...
```

See: https://bugs.python.org/issue20903